# Редактирование буфера консоли в терминале Linux

Tags: linux, консоль, linux-mint

В Windows есть библиотека `Windows.h` для *C++*, которая позволяет изменять символ в определённой строке и определёммном столбце буфера консоли. Как можно сделать такое в терминале *Linux*.

Я видел такое, например, во время скачивания пакетов, когда меняется процент загрузки.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: ncurses, например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я верно вас понял то вам нужен `tput`

вот простой пример, в виде однострочника, для удобного запуска в терминале:

```
tput sc;tput civis;for i in {0..100..10};do echo -n "== $i% ==";sleep 0.2;tput rc;done;echo;tput cnorm
```

подробнее можно посмотреть к примеру [здесь](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php)